# A regular checking and cleaning of files in the server

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, timeout, filesystems

I have the following back-end with `socket.io`. Each time we open a connection by `localhost:3000` in a new browser tab, a file named with the socket id is created in the folder `tmp/` of the server.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(3000);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.writeFile("tmp/" + socket.id, "hello", function (err) {
        if (err) { return console.log(err) };
        console.log('a file is saved!');
    });
});
```

Because sockets may be disconnected, inactive or idle later. I want to set a simple cleaning rule in the server. For example, **at `4pm` of everyday, I want to delete all the files that were saved before `4pm` of yesterday.**

So does anyone know how to set up this regular checking+deletion every day?

**Edit 1:** Following the discussion with @georoot , I realise I need to send a notification message to the connections whose tmp file was just removed. And I would prefer to have all the **network** code within the website nodejs code (though the nodejs code may call external bash).

Comment: `cron job` did you try that?

Comment: I see... So are you saying I don't have to implement this in my website javascript code? I could well make a separate scheduled job in my server?

Comment: Exactly .. it is related to `fs` there is no need for any nodejs. Let me write a simple bash script to help you out :)

Comment: But wait, there is still an advantage of implementing this in the website. Because I may want to send a message to the (eg, idle) connections whose tmp file is just removed.

Comment: You can do that in bash also.You see in linux everything is files, you in bash it would be something like `echo "message" > /tmp/socketid` Assuming i am following correctly and /tmp/socketid is created but socketio library.... if thats not the case, you can write a node script and invoke that before deleting the file to send message to connection

Comment: I don't really understand your last comment... How could I send messages to connections **by bash**?

Comment: in bash you have the connection id from the filename. Simple call `node my_script.js $id`, this would pass $id as a param to node script which you can parse and send message to

Comment: But this `my_script.js` is separate from my website code, right? I would prefer to manage all the code together. Isn't there a nodejs solution for my question?

Comment: Sure rather, you can use nodejs to delete those files, pretty sure there should be some alternative to cron job also in nodejs.

Comment: Thank you, the discussion is helpful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron)? **EDIT:** In combination with the [fs.stats documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats) you can use the mtime (modified time) to filter each file. And [fs.readdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) to get the files.

Comment: ok... then how could i remove all the files whose last save was before 4pm of yesterday?

Comment: this is best answer among others , and will quickly get you what you need. - You need to setup node-cron, and then actually use `fs` module to do your filesystem checks and jobs. Working at my side.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of bash related question than nodejs.

### Identify files for deletion

First lets write a script that will check for files that were created `24 hours` before the current time. To get the time of file

```
date -r $filename
```

Run inside loop to find files that needs to be deleted. You can simply pipe to output from `ls` over here.

### Delete files

Simply delete the files using

```
rm -rf $filename
```

that were identified in last step.

### Add to cron

Make a cron job to invoke this script everyday.